# N-M relationship unknow attribute error with create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here are my migrations:

```
class CreateTests < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tests do |t|
      t.string :value

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateQuestions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :questions do |t|
      t.string :title

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateQuestionsTests < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :questions_tests do |t|
      t.integer :test_id
      t.integer :question_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Now in the rails console I created a test object and a question object

```
test = Test.create(value: "10")
question = Question.create(title: "blablabla")
```

If now I do `test.questions.create(question_id: question.id)` I get the following error:

`ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: question_id`

How is that?

Comment: Did you do a `rake db:migrate`

Comment: also did you define your associations in the models?

Comment: @SamS would've thought this be already in place

Comment: i made all, cuz if i launch `test.questions.size` I get 0

Answer (score 0):

If you are using has_and_belongs_to_many relationship, you must to have relation table without id and stamps

```
class CreateQuestionsTests < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :questions_tests, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer :test_id
      t.integer :question_id
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you want to do a Rich association here, if so you should declare relations in your models like this :

Test.rb

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :questions_tests
    has_many :questions, :through => :questions_tests # here you tell rails that your Test model has many questions if you go through questions_tests
end
```

Question.rb

```
 class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :questions_tests
     has_many :tests, :through => :questions_tests # here you tell rails that your Question model has many tests if you go through questions_tests
 end
```

QuestionTest.rb

```
class QuestionTest < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :test
    belongs_to :question
end
```

with this you can traverse the associations table (questions_tests) directly like you want : `test.questions.create(question_id: question.id)`, and you have also this possibility :

```
test = Test.create(value: "10")
question = Question.create(title: "blablabla")
test.questions_tests << question # or question.questions_tests << test
```